# Looking for a Verb / Idiom to Make a Wish Come True

Tags: verbs, idiom-requests

Let say I wish to have a car, and somebody bought me that car.
Which verbs or idioms can describe the "somebody's" action?

Comment: He made my wish came true.

Comment: @ermanen Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

*He **fulfilled** my wish for a car*

or

*He **satisfied** my wish for a car*

Answer (score 6):

A standard phrase is **grant a wish**. In fact, a search of [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=grant%20a%20wish&oq=grant%20a%20wish&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j0l2.2813j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es%5fsm=93&ie=UTF-8) reflects that numerous organizations use the phrase as part of their names or slogans.

A related phrase is *[fairy godmother](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/fairy%20godmother)*. This is an idiom for a wish grantor.

> A generous benefactor.

Comment: It was interesting. Unfortunately, I should choose one answer, and I found Alex's more relevant. Vote up :)

Comment: @a The beauty of language is the many ways we can say things and the subtle differences we can convey by those choices. You select the words that best convey what *you* want to convey. No need to apologize.

Answer (score 4):

What about ***realize your wish***?

Comment: Can I use it as: "I try to realize your wish?". Or, "I can realize your dream?"

Comment: Indeed you can!